# PHP script to update rrd database

Tags: php, scripting, snmp, rrdtool

I must developing an network monitor to monitoring several components using snmp. I save all received data in a round robin database.

I started to create an web based configuration center, that allows users to add devices to be monitored and access all the graphs (using rrdtool) of all devices.

I must run an daily, week, month and yearly update of the database.

My question is, how can i launch an script that executes an snmp command to fetch the data from the device and stores it on the databse and runs on background ? By background, i mean that it is a process that not depends if the user has logged in in the web configuration page or not.

I never did something in PHP, therefore i am asking you.

I hope you can help me out. Thank you in advance.
Best regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed such a system a few years ago. We used [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net), in combination with [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org) and [Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping). Of course, if your needs are simpler, you could use cron scripts to fetch your data. But Cacti is definetely worth a look (as well as Nagios, but unlike Cacti, it's not specifically targetted at RRD files)

Note that none of these systems require PHP. They run standalone, as daemons. It's then pretty straightforward to write a web interface on top of that.

Comment: It can be something simple. Cron seems to be a good idea. Can someone provide me with examples, how Cron works with php scripts ? Do I have fully control over the script ?

Comment: I don't really know if you'd better go with raw cron scripts, or Cacti, because you said you were writing a web GUI ... which is exactly what Cacti is. However, writing cron scripts is outside the scope of this topic so I suggest you 1) ask a specific question on your problem and 2) accept this answer :)